# Used dd to backup a disk, now want to look at the filesystem

Tags: backup, dd, fdisk

I `dd` copied `/dev/sdd`

`sudo dd if=/dev/sdd of=backup.img`

`sudo fdisk backup.img`

```
Command (m for help): p

Disk backup.img: 143.3 GB, 143274860544 bytes
61 heads, 35 sectors/track, 131069 cylinders, total 279833712 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003c0d1



      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    backup.img1            2048   286747999   143372976    5  Extended
    backup.img5            4096   286746623   143371264   83  Linux

Command (m for help):q
```

`sudo mount backup.img /mnt/disk3`

doesn't work.

Not sure what to do now.

Any suggestions?

---

Time to start over:

Sounds like I should run dd on the partition, not the entire disk.
Here's the output of fdisk:

```
sreeve@cebuild:~$ sudo fdisk /dev/sdd

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/sdd: 146.8 GB, 146814976000 bytes

61 heads, 35 sectors/track, 134308 cylinders, total 286748000 sectors

Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk identifier: 0x0003c0d1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System

/dev/sdd1            2048   286747999   143372976    5  Extended

/dev/sdd5            4096   286746623   143371264   83  Linux

Command (m for help):
```

So should I do this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdd1 of=/home/sreeve/backup.img
```

or this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdd5 of=/home/sreeve/backup.img
```

Comment: Try the `sdd5`. `sdd1` is an extended (logical) partition, not a "real" one. It is basically a container for `sdd5`, your data, the part you care about is on `sdd5`.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `loop` option to `mount`:

```
sudo mount -o loop backup.img /mnt/disk3
```

I am not sure how this will work on an image of an entire disk as opposed to a single partition, I have never tried it. The above works to mount partition images though.

Answer (score 0):

Download AcetoneISO from the ubuntu software center. This has the ability to mount and convert .img files.

Comment: Thanks so much.  I will definitely try AcetoneISO.  Meanwhile, gparted has a data recovery option which I am currently trying.  I'll post an update on both methods when I'm done testing.